# PHP made shopping list with $_SESSION['cart'] array but array stays empty

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, session, cart

I'm currently making a session shopping cart where I can add and delete products with a link underneath every product. You can check it out here if you prefer it visualized: http://www.bgc-testomgeving.nl/sem

Anyway, somehow when I click the link of the product nothing seems to happen except from the URL changing, but the adding to the `$_SESSION['cart']` doesn't seem to occur.

This is the code of the link underneath every product to add it to the cart: `echo '<a href="action=add&id=' .$id. '">Voeg toe </a>';`

With `$id` being: `$id = get_the_ID();` from WordPress query. This part works however because the URL of the `<a>` is right I think.

Here I check if there is already a `$_SESSION['cart']` active, if not I make one. Also, I check if the item ID is already in `cart`, if not, I do the `array_push()` and if so, I use unset. See underneath:

```
<?php session_start(); 
require("dbconnect.php");
?>
<?php 
     if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
         $cart = array();
         $_SESSION['cart'] = $cart;
     }  

    if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=="add"){             
        $id=intval($_GET['id']); 
                if(in_array($id, $_SESSION['cart'])){
                    if (($key = array_search($id, $_SESSION['cart'] !== false))){
                        unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);
                    }
                }
                else {
        array_push($_SESSION['cart'],$id);          
                }
    } ?>
```

I print the array of the `$_SESSION['cart']` plus the `session_id()` on the page to check if it worked with the following code in index.php:

```
<?php print "Test session number: "; 
            echo session_id();
            echo '<br>';
            echo serialize($_SESSION['cart']);
            ?>
```

So my question is, why is the `$id` not pushed to the `$_SESSION['cart']`

EDIT: I FOUND THE PROBLEM, I FORGOT TO ADD A ? TO THE ARRAY SO THE $_GET didn't know it was a parameter

Comment: Okay, so locally this works perfectly fine. What server settings could be the problem? I actually have no idea, only thing I know is that register_globals is disabled, could that be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Script is working.
I copy your code in a PHP-File on my server and it is doing what you expect.
I can add IDs to my "cart".
Is your session working correctly?
Some wrong configs on your Server?

Comment: Thanks for trying, I was setting up my own server already to try if that was the problem. Is register globals supposed to be enabled? Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: No, register globals is per default deactivated. Is your browser maybe rejecting your Cookies(private mode or something), so the Session is always restarting and always empty?

Comment: Hey @Candyman1332 the problem is solved, I forgot a question-mark in front of my action so <a href="?action.....>  fixed the problem. Took me 4 hours of searching.

Comment: thx for the responds. I saw it at the moment when i sent the comment. :D

Answer (score 0):

var_dump the $_SESSION['cart'] before and after the array_push($_SESSION['cart'],$id); and check the values.

Comment: I'm settings up my local server right now and will do this ASAP and post the results here. My hosting company won't allow me to change my php.ini file so I can't debug right now.